# jQuery on(click)/click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am very bad at UI design so i used bootstrap and jquery to help me alittle bit.
I am trying to bind jQuery event to nav bar, so when  user click  p tag on nav bar it should fire a click event. however, it doesn't. No matter i use jQuery("#logOff").click()  or on("click","#logOff",function())
it just not firing event. 
below is my sample code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {


  jQuery(document).on( 'click','#logOff', function (eve) {
    alert("haha");
  });

  // this one not work too
jQuery("#logOff").click(function (e){
   alert("haha");
  });
});
```

this is my html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <p class="navbar-brand" >test</p>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


          <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li ><p id="#nickName" style="cursor: pointer" class="navbar-brand">Link</p></li>
            <li ><p id="#logOff" style="cursor: pointer" class="navbar-brand">log Off</p></li>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `#` symbol from your id declarations - it's not required.

```
<li ><p id="nickName" style="cursor: pointer" class="navbar-brand">Link</p></li>
<li ><p id="logOff" style="cursor: pointer" class="navbar-brand">log Off</p></li>
```

The `#` when used in selectors searches for ids, so `#logoff` in your jQuery selector is saying *find the element with `id="logoff"`* which won't match with `id="#logoff"`

Comment: OMG, how stupid am i, i spent 6 hour at searching but not checking my code. Thank you so much.